# USB Ubuntu Installation stuck before entering the installation UI

Tags: system-installation, hardware, usb-installation

This might be a PC assembling problem or a hardware problem.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 via USB for my new machine that assembled by myself. I only plug in RAM and CPU into the motherboard so as to exclude issues from other hardware. Ideally, it will allow me to enter the installation until the step of choosing where to install the OS.

Here are what I got.

1. Initially, this screen flashed briefly, lasting less than a second.
   [Image 1]
2. Subsequently, I was directed to the GRUB menu, where I selected the 'Try or Install Ubuntu' option.
   [Image 2]
3. Upon selection, a screen appeared but quickly transitioned to the next one within roughly a second.
   [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8rL9.jpg)
4. Next and lastly, I was met with a screen that remained static indefinitely.
   [Image 4]

The monitor is connected to the motherboard directly; The USB stick has been tested on other machine and is able to install the OS; I tried secure boot disabled/enabled; I tried UEFI/CSM.

Here is a list of hardware I am using:

- CPU: CORE i9 13th GEN
- CPU cooler: PURE LOOP 2 FX
- Mother Board: MSI B760 GAMING PLUS WIFI
- PSU: EVGA SuperNOVA 2000 G+ 2000W
- RAM: Trident Z5 RGB

Please help me. I get stuck here for already one month! Thank you in advance for any kind of help. Have a nice day!

**[Update 10.27]**

I flashed the BIOS with the most updated version for my motherboard B760 GAMING PLUS WIFI (from 7D98vH1 to 7D98vH4) and tried to install ubuntu 22.04.2 (ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) again. It first showed the same screen as in **Image 4** for a while and turned into [Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTuUE.jpg) after I pressed the enter button.

And then I created a new USB stick with ubuntu 23 (ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso). It showed **Image 4** again and stoped there forever.

Besides, when I was trying to install either 22.04 or 23.10, I tried multiple times by manually restarting the machine when it was stuck. Sometimes I entered the GRUB menu and selected 'try or install ubuntu' and stuck at **Image 4**; sometimes it did not show the GRUB menu and directly showed [Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZVEi.jpg) and stuck there forever. And sometimes the little white circle in **Image 4** or **Image 6** was moving and sometimes it did not.

**[Update 11.01]**

Following guiverc's suggestions, I tried again to install 22.04.2 (ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) with **quiet splash** removed and **nomodeset** added. Please check [Image7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A26V5.jpg) for the command. [Image8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk91v.jpg) was what I got after 5mins and [Image9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaFx5.jpg) was after 2hours. It looks like a filesystem issue but not sure how to fix it.

Like I said, I did not install SSD during my previous installation attempts. I am not sure if it was the problem but I just plugged it into the motherboard and did everything again. [Image10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rchAU.jpg) was where it stopped. The kernel panic seems to be a severe problem and it may be caused by hardware or software. Where should I start to troubleshoot?

**[Update 11.01]-2**

I tried to install 22.04.3 and this is what I got [Image11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGTKu.jpg). I guess it is unusual to exit with IRQs disabled. Should I check the hardware and where should I start?

Note: I removed links for Image1 (error: file /boot/ not found.), Image2 (GNU GRUB menu) and Image4 (MSI and Ubuntu logo) due to the forum reputation limitation.

**[Update 11.02]**

This time I tried a 18.04.6. This ubuntu has separate options for trying ubuntu without installing and installing ubuntu so I was able to select trying ubuntu this time. First time I entered into the live ubuntu environment but it failed to install the ubuntu. When I tried to do it again, it showed segmentation fault. Third time is another error of kernel panic. I used nomodeset and with no quiet splash. All steps were the same for these three times of trying. Crazy! Wondering why it failed and why it gave different error message for different attempts.

And tried again, it says **Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference at /usr/share/per15/Debconf/Iterator.pm line 13.**

Comment: Instead of 22.04, try 23.10 for for new hardware.  Switch to 24.04 when it comes out for a Long Term Support version. Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO and do any media checks if offered?

Comment: You mention 22.04 but without any specifics as to which 22.04 product, nor which ISO and thus kernel stack you actually tried; why not tell us instead of making it guess (22.04 ISOs are available using the older 5.15 GA kernel, 5.19 kernel & 6.2 kernel yet you didn't specify which you tried?) Image 3 looked like boot messages (expected on a vmlinuz boot) & image 4 I wonder if it was a `plymouth` screen (using OEM thus the MSI logo, but you didn't specify what 22.04 product/ISO you're asking about so I don't know what is expected for your choice.

Comment: Do you have video card? What drives? Have you updated MSI board to latest firmware? And if SSD updated to latest firmware? Are you booting live installer in UEFI boot mode from UEFI boot menu. Is system set for UEFI boot. while it should work with UEFI Secure boot on, often UEFI but secure boot off is often a bit easier.

Comment: @guiverc My apologize for unclear information and thanks a lot for your reply. I was trying to install 22.04.2 (ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso). I also tried 23.10.1 (ubuntu-23.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso) but it did not work as I mentioned in the [Update 10.27]. Please let me know if you need any other information. I will try to provide anything I have. Thank you!

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you for your reply. I tried 23.10 as described in [Update 10.27]. All USB sticks are tested in another machine and it works. Do you think it can verify the USB is actually working?

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for your reply. I am not using a SSD and I do not have an additional video card. I am using the integrated display interface by directly connecting my screen to the motherboard. As described in [Update 10.27], I flashed BIOS to the newest version. But it is still not working. I also tried secure boot disabled/enabled and both UEFI and CSM mode, not working. Please let me know if you have any other idea. Thanks!

Comment: Your attempted 22.04 used the 5.19 kernel and `ubiquity` installer (*22.04.3 uses 6.2 but that likely won't change anything*). Your choice of 23.10.1 ISO uses the 6.5 kernel (*newer kernel/kernel modules or 'drivers'*) and `ubuntu-desktop-installer`.  Have you tried booting using *safe graphics*?  (`nomodeset` linux parameter will use a fallback/simpler graphics)

Comment: I should also have suggested removing the `quiet splash` from the kernel line (ie. edit grub entry you select using "E") so you see all kernel messages on boot; you may learn more from that.   Me I'd also boot to *runlevel 1* and explore the system that was installed, but I'm not sure how to describe anything as I'd not be looking for anything specific; just something that looked *unexpected*.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your comments again. I tried booting using safe graphics but nothing changed. It still stuck at the MSI and Ubuntu logo screen. Besides, I tried removing quiet splash and adding nomodeset when booting. Please check my update above. Please note that this is a new machine and no existing system is installed. Thank you again and looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Image 9 & 10 look like kernel [panic] dump to me... where assuming your media (*ISO write to thumb-drive*) is good (*I'd verify that on two other machines, doing live boots there and ensuring the media check completes; one box as close to your intended box as you have & other something different*) the 5.19 kernel on 22.04.2 isn't acting well on that hardware. I'd thus try 5.15 kernel (22.04/22.04.1) or 6.2 (22.04.3) and see if the same as those ISOs will use different kernel/kernel.modules; 6.2 is the newest for 22.04 with 6.5 still not available; I'd use 23.10 ISO for that try.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for your quick reply! I tried 22.04.3 and results are in [Update 11.01]-2. I will double check the media as you suggested. But any thoughts about the Image11? Should I keep trying other kernels? Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: @guiverc Hi guiverc, I double checked the media (as you suggested, entered into the live boots and media check passed) and it is working! Besides, I tried also 18.04.6 and was able to enter 'try ubuntu without installing'. But it still failed to install with different error messages as shown in my last update. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? I'm facing the same issue with MPG X570 Gaming Plus. I found that both of those Mobo officially don't support Linux, only Windows is in operating system section: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B760-GAMING-PLUS-WIFI/Specification